# When initializing an object of a class type with braces (direct list initialization), where are the arguments passed?

Tags: c++

Example:

```
class A {
private:
    int x;
public:
    A(int i);
};

A::A(int i)
    : x(i) {}

int main() {
    A test{ 5 };
}
```

Do the braces function like parentheses usually do? How is the constructor function with a parameter called without the use of parentheses?

Comment: Constructors aren’t ever “called” directly; their argument lists are just specified by the initialization rules, often to be a list of expressions in `()` **or** `{}`.